# error: The server does not support version 3.1 of the J2EE Web module specification

Tags: java, ibm-cloud

I want to run my java web services app on IBM bluemix server for deploying it on Bluemix. When I run it on bluemix server it gives an error: The server does not support version 3.1 of the J2EE Web module specification
I tried changing version 3.1 but it is not allowing me to do so.
please provide a solution

Comment: I did changes as u said. But still its showing the same reason. And in project properties it is still showing 3.1 version where i am not able to change it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WebSphere Application Server Liberty Profile does not currently have Web 3.1 project support. Set the web-app version to 3.0 in your web.xml like this:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
version="3.0">
```

Comment: I did changes as u said. But still its showing the same reason. And in project properties it is still showing 3.1 version where i am not able to change it.

Comment: Right click on your project -> Properties -> Project Facets then set Dynamic Web Module to 3.  If eclipse is not permitting you to change it, it might be easier for you to create a new dynamic web project with the  version and copy source over. You can also try to manually update the eclipse settings file http://scrapillars.blogspot.in/2014/02/how-to-change-project-facet-in-eclipse.html?m=1

Comment: Great! If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is supported but there is always the Tomcat Java build pack. You can try it by adding "java_buildpack" to your manifest as buildpack: java_buildpack or by adding it as a -b argument in your `cf push` command.